# .flv videos are not supported by Media webpart

Tags: 2013

.flv videos cannot be added to media web-part. Is there any solution to add .flv videos in a page?

Comment: Steve Jobs succeeded in taking Flash to the grave. So Flash and thus Flash Video (.flv) is dead..and plugin support in Browsers is soon gone as well. So you can only play .flv with the right Server and Browser extensions (Now if Steve wanted this for himself.. it must have been some bad-ass tech)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to convert your flash video to `asf, avi, mpg, mp3, mp4, ogg, ogv, webm, wma or wmv` to use it it a media web part. There are several converters available online.

See [Supported file formats in the SharePoint 2013 Media Web Part](https://thesharepointfarm.com/2013/01/supported-file-formats-in-the-sharepoint-2013-media-web-part/)